# ¿Como configurar bien vsftpd? - CentOS7

Tags: ftp, centos7

en mi día a dias montándome mi servidor he llegado al punto de querer instalar un servicio ftp en mi centos 7. llevo ya 3 días y hoy por fin he conseguido acceder, sin embargo, la carpeta a la que accedo se supone que debería contener elementos y no es así.

Os describo el proceso:

Instalamos vsftpd

```
sudo yum -y install vsftpd
```

configuramos /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Estos son los parámetros:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Reiniciamos apache y lo habilitamos al reinicio

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
sudo systemctl enable vsftpd
```

configuramos las reglas del firewall

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

creamos el usuario para el servicio ftp

```
sudo useradd ftpuser
sudo passwd ftpuser
```

incorporamos al usuario fpt al grupo apache

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache ftpuser
```

y asignamos /var/www/html/ como directorio home para el usuario ftp(pues vsftp no me permite usar ninguno que cuelgue de /home... Eso o me da unos problemas terribles)

```
sudo usermod -d /var/www/html/ ftpuser
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realidad no reflejada:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/Tggz7t5.png]

Alguien sabe donde fallo? como he dicho llevo 3 días y esta es la primera vez que filezilla me deja loggear, pero a un directorio fantasma.

PD: todo esto viene porque wordpress pide ftp para sus actualizaciones

Comment: hay dice que tas en el directorio `/bin/` no en `/var/www/html/`

Comment: Ahora compruebo tu respuesta, pero no, ahí dice que estoy en /bin en mi maquina. Es la parte derecha la que me interesa. La izquierda es el sistema de carpetas local por si quiero transferir ficheros desde la misma aplicación.

Comment: Ya agregaste las reglas al Iptables?

Comment: es una instalación mínima de centos7 que, al contrario que centos 6 no incluye iptables.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

el el archivo `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` agrega:

```
chroot_list_enable=YES
local_root=/var/www/html/
```

y luego solo reiniciamos

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

esto hara que el directorio por defecto para `vsftpd` siempre sea `/var/www/html/` y apenas accedas te envia a esta ruta!

Comment: Gracias, no me funciona tal como dices pero parece que por ahí van los tiros.
Si lo hago exactamente como indicas no puedo entrar, sin embargo parece que ese parámetro es para indicar un fichero donde se ponen que usuarios pueden acceder.

Voy a ver si siguiendo esta vía consigo hacerlo bien. Te cuento en cuanto tenga algo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: perdon fue mi error parese que no se pego todo :v

Comment: me esta pasando algo curioso. por ejemplo. con mi propio usuario puedo acceder a la carpeta que tengo definida como /home, de hecho puedo acceder a cualquiera, supongo que por ser admin. sin embargo, con el usuario ftpuser me deja acceder a todas las carpetas salvo a las que he especificado como home, he realizado ya varias pruebas y es super raro

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado. Finalmente era tema de SeLinux, dejo lo que falta para tenerlo configurado. No hace falta modificar nada de lo que se hace en el primer post, solo añadir esta información.

se añade una linea al /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf

```
sudo echo "allow_writeable_chroot=YES" >> /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

Se configura SeLinux

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_rw_t /var/www/html
sudo restorecon -Rvv /var/www/html
sudo setsebool -P tftp_home_dir 1
sudo setsebool -P ftpd_full_access 1
```

Reiniciamos apache, lo habilitamos al reinicio y ya lo tenemos.

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
sudo systemctl enable vsftpd
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

en el archivo /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf agrega:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
```

Y para usuarios que no son del sistema usa:

```
guest_enable=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
```

> Cita en bloque